# How to efficiently find the largest integer closest to the mean of two integers in increments of 100,000?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

Let's say I am given integers `x` and `y` (satisfying `x <= y` with ones digit of `0` so they are, in particular, divisible by two). Then I know that their average `avg = ((x+y) / 2)` is an integer as well. I would like to find this midpoint rounded up to a resolution of `100`. In other words if my two inputs are 75200 and 75300 then the avg is 75250 and rounded up to the nearest `100` (but without exceeding or equaling the bigger number) forces the answer to be 75200.

How can I implement this logic without first dividing everything by 100 and using the following floating point arithmetic:

`x + std::floor((y - x) * .5 * 100 + .5)*0.01`

In other words, how can I do the above without floating point values but obtain the same behavior at the resolution of `100` instead of `0.01`?

Comment: What about using mod. Is it allowed?

Comment: if x were 75202, would the answer still be 75200?  because that's not what your code gives.

Comment: "... then the avg is 75250 and rounded up to the nearest 100 (but without exceeding or equaling the bigger number) forces the answer to be 75200." -- Don't you mean the answer is 75300?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compute the average you can do

```
avg = (x + y) / 2
```

(BTW, integer addition and division by 2 are very cheap operations even on small microcontrollers.)

To round this to the nearest multiple of 100 (corresponding to your floating-point example) you can do

```
result = ((avg + 50) / 100) * 100
```

as integer division rounds down to the nearest integer.  By changing the `50` to `0` you can always round down, while changing it to `99` always rounds up.

**Edit:** Note that this method for rounding doesn't work for negative numbers. Since integer division rounds towards zero, in that case you'll need to subtract the `50`, subtract `99` to always round down and subtract `0` to always round up.

Comment: how 'bout ((x+y+100)/200)*100

Answer (score 2):

Your problematic example requires strong conditions:

- the difference between x and y needs to be not greater than 100
- y % 100 must be 0

So for most cases, a simple rounded average is perfect for you:

```
avg100 = avg - (avg % 100) + 100
```

The tricky part is fixing the remaining error without a condition - if you want to avoid conditions, or slow operations.

For this, the best way is to use a multiplication, and split the expression into two:

```
avg100 = avg - (avg % 100)
avg100 += 100 * !!(y - avg100)
```

For most cases, y is greater than avg100. For this case, the `!!` operator will return 1. In the rare case when they equal, it will return a 0, and it won't change the value.

(I don't know if the compiler will really generate a code without conditions for the '!!' operator, but I don't have a batter idea, and if it is possible, I think it will. If not, this code is still short and easy to understand.)

Also, you can calculate the average using the following expression:

```
avg = y - (y-x)/2
```

Or even change the division into bit shift for optimization.

This won't require for both of the numbers to be even, just to be the same parity.